# What's the procedure for seeking a psak?

Tags: how-to, posek-psak-decisor-ruling

I need a psak on a complicated (to me) halachic issue. I'm not currently affiliated with a shul, so I have no daily contact with rabbanim, and I've never needed a psak before. How does one do this? Should I just go to a local shul and ask for an appointment with the rav? Should I research who specializes in specific areas of halacha? What's the protocol?

Comment: You may have to ask your rabbi for a psak on how to find a psak. In any case, I don't think this forum is a means to find an answer to this type of question.

Comment: OK, help me out. Why not? I'm asking a procedural question that (I assume) can be definitively answered; isn't that within the guidelines?

Comment: @DanF I don't see why not.  We don't *give* p'sak, and we can't help a person figure out which local rabbi he should consult, but the general *process* for doing this seems no different than any of our other how-to/community-oriented questions.

Comment: @MonicaCellio dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69909/759

Comment: @DoubleAA very closely related.  crmdgn, are you asking how to find a rabbi to be *your* rabbi when you have these questions, or are you asking how to get one-shot answers (where ask-the-rabbi sites might come into play)?

Comment: I hadn't thought of it that way, TBH. I'd prefer a personal interaction, but I'm unlikely to join a new congregation.

Comment: Indeed you should go to a local shul and ask the rav if you can book some time to discuss a personal situation and get his psak. If this is a complicated area of halacha, you might indeed need to research who can best help you. Be aware that in cases of *dinei mamonot* (financial conflicts), a rav is unlikely to give you a psak without hearing both sides. You would then need a bet din to hear both perspectives and issue a psak. This is a different procedure. Does it help? Maybe if you say a bit more about what area of halacha, someone will be able to direct you a bit more

Comment: Possibly a duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47398. Also related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36454 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34566 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8303

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since many times a psak, a Jewish legal decision, is dependent upon your local circumstances, it is best to initially seek out a local, qualified Orthodox Rabbi.

Without knowing your specific location, you will need to search yourself.

If you do an internet search for your locale together with the search words "Orthodox', "Beis Din", "Beit Din", and "synagogue", you should get a contact phone number. If that fails, try calling the nearest Chabad House to you and ask if they have a phone number for the nearest Orthodox Beit Din.

Call and explain that you would like to speak with and possibly meet with the Rabbi or Rabbis for an answer to a halachic question. It may not be as complicated as you think and might be something they can answer over the telephone. Don't feel stressed about it. A Rav's life is dedicated to providing answers for those who don't know what to do in matters of halacha.

Although it isn't required, it is customary in many places to make a small monetary donation for making use of the Rabbis time and expertise like with any other professional. It's all according to ones ability to pay.