# Finding a Rav for a woman

Tags: rabbis

How do I, a woman, go about finding a personal Rav (in Israel)? I see that you have addressed the question for men but not for women. We don't have the same opportunities for meeting Rabbanim as do men. We are told: ask a Rav who knows you well. But I don't know how to find someone who I'll get to know well and they'll get to know me well.

Comment: How did you choose a shul?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, user13619. This site is not designed for every good question. Questions that are primarily opinion based, are discouraged. This question would seem to qualify. Some suggestions would include, seeking rabbis associated with your _beit k'nesset_, and /or asking friends if they know a rabbi who they feel meets their needs. Hatslaha rabba!

Comment: "I see that you have addressed the question for men" Where? Which opportunities do men have that women don't?

Comment: @DoubleAA http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47398/how-to-go-about-finding-a-personal-rav the question doesn't ask about men, but evidently the OP feels that the answers most focused on men.

Comment: @mevaqesh I don't see how that's not a dupe

Comment: @DoubleAA i agree.