# Will a mezuzah be kosher if installed by a non-Jew?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, mezuzah

I'm wondering if a non-Jew simply does the hammering, whether the mezuzah will still be considered kosher so long as the proper blessing is said.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works? Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 3):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BafNIu_hXrw) (after 1'30") reports a similar question was asked to R Yosef Shalom Eliashiv who brought a Maharam Shick that it was allowed for a non-Jew to put up a mezuza if a person is old/sick and can't do it himself. He argues the *mitzva* is to have a mezuza not to put it on.

However, others (the Sdei Chemed, R Shmuel Wosner) argue that putting up the mezuza has to be *lishma*, for its own sake, which only a Jew can do.

Since it is a dispute, the specific details of the case (e.g., the reason a Jew cannot hang it to start with, whether that Jew would be able to finish the hanging if a non-Jew helps) will be crucial and one should ask a rabbi.

Comment: Thanks.  This is perhaps a separate question, but in a situation like this where there is a dispute, how does one avoid "Rabbi shopping" (consciously or unconsciously) to get the answer one is looking for?  (I'm thinking of a scene in the Israeli TV show "Srugim" where a wife angrily tells her husband that she's sure he'd be able to find a liberal Rabbi to approve his side of an argument.)

Comment: Good followup. Might even be worth a question of its own. One goes to a serious Rav who is God fearing and therefore will give you the straight halacha. There is a broader question of how one goes about to finding someone like this, who in addition will want to get to know you and find the right ruling for you. Assuming you are able to finish hanging the mezuza, e.g., putting the last nail, having someone help you put it up and you finish putting it in place might be a very good compromise

Comment: Actually we have that question: [How to go about finding a personal Rav](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47398/11501)

Comment: Thanks.  Both comments very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A non-Jew should not put up a Mezuzah. If it was already put up by a non-Jew, most authorities rule that it should be taken down and reattached by a Jew. There is a question if a new blessing should be made [and therefore one would not make the blessing]. (שערי המזוזה טז/ ג הערה ו writes at length about this question.)
[image][image]]

Comment: Is this the conclusion of the lengthy treatment in שערי מזוזה or your own?